# requestLocationUpdates() doesn't work on a real smartphone

Tags: android, android-location

I'm developing an app and I need the location of the user 24/7, even when the app is closed. To solve that, I have an AlarmManager which every minute execute the code to get the location

```
public class LocationTracker extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_GET_LOCATION;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    //private LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) thi;
    private LocationListener mLocationListener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public static final String ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATE = "com.example.alwaysafe.UPDATE_LOCATION";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }


        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10f, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.i("LISTENER", ".");
                if (location != null) {
                 Log.i("LATITUDE LISTENER", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                    Log.i("LONGITUDE LISTENER", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code works when the app is running on the emulator but when i try to run it on a real smartphone, the AlarmManager is activated but it doesn't get the location

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these of two arguments for `requestLocationUpdates()`

- The second argument next to the GPS_PROVIDER means the minimum time interval in milliseconds between location updates.
- The third is the minimum distance between location updates, in meters

First, you can try to set the distance from 10 meters to 0 to get out of this criteria.